# A way to reset/restart the Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one

So I recently started playing Mortal Kombat X and I saw I got an achievement so I held the home button to look at it. But my game froze and only the home button would work. So I turned off my Xbox but the flashing light kept going on and off. So I eventually got pretty pissed and unplugged my Xbox then plugged it back in. Now it won't turn on. I've only had it for about a month and a half and it's already giving me troubles I won't be happy. So I'm wondering if there's a way to like restart it, like holding down the home and power button for the iphone? And that would make my Xbox turn back on, Thanks!

Comment: just as an aside, check to see if your power pack (the boxy thing on the cord between the wall outlet and the Xbox) has clogged air vents. If dust or something clogs those vents, the power pack will get a red light instead of yellow and shut down the whole system.

Comment: The flashing light when turning off means that it does some clean-up. Happens to all Operating Systems. You shouldn't interfere with this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had to talk to Xbox Support but it turns out I had to plug my Xbox into a different outlet

Answer (score 1):

If the Xbox wont turn on after plugging it back in, the problem may be power/hardware related, so a restart may not be possible.

But, the way to do a hard reset on your Xbox One is to hold your finger on the glowing power button (front of console) for about ten seconds. This is equivalent to doing the Restart option through the Xbox One system settings, and will do a "hard reset" of the Xbox OS (so longer boot up time even if youve set it to Instant On).